# requestfactory complain about find method

Tags: spring, gwt, requestfactory

I have a spring (3.1) application with a service and dao layer.
I try to use requestfactory (gwt 2.4) withi this spring layer.

Here some of my class

My domain class

```
public class Account {
  Long id;
  String username;
  // get, set
}
```

The bridge between spring and gwt

```
public class SpringServiceLocator implements ServiceLocator {

    @Override
    public Object getInstance(Class<?> clazz) {
        HttpServletRequest request = RequestFactoryServlet.getThreadLocalRequest();
        ServletContext servletContext = request.getSession().getServletContext();
        ApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
        return context.getBean(clazz);
    }
}
```

My account proxy

```
@ProxyFor(value=Account.class, locator = AccountLocator.class)
public interface AccountProxy extends EntityProxy{
    public Long getId();
    public String getUsername();

    public void setUsername(String userName);
    public void setId(Long id);    
}
```

RequestContext class

```
@Service(locator = SpringServiceLocator.class, value =AccountService.class)
public interface AccountRequest extends RequestContext {
    Request<List<AccountProxy>> loadAllAccounts();
}
```

My requestFactory class

```
public interface AccountRequestFactory extends RequestFactory {
    AccountRequest accountRequest();
}
```

My spring service

```
public interface AccountService {
    public List<Account> loadAllAccounts();
}

@Service
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService{
    @Autowired
    private AccountDAO accountDAO;
}
```

Account locator to avoid to put method in the entity

```
public class AccountLocator extends Locator<Account, Long> {

    @Autowired
    private AccountDAO accountDAO;

    @Override
    public Account create(Class<? extends Account> clazz) {
       return new Account();

    }
}
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.calibra" />
<bean id="accountService" class="org.calibra.server.service.AccountServiceImpl"/>
<bean id="accountDAO" class="org.calibra.server.dao.AccountDAOImpl"/>
```

The demo work but i get this error:

***com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.UnexpectedException: Could not find static method with a single parameter of a key type***

Also on my AccountProxy i get this complain (a warning)

***The domain type org.calibra.domain.Account has no Account findAccount(java.lang.Long) method. Attempting to send a AccountProxy to the server will result in a server error.***

I don't want to add a find methond in my domain class.
I tried to put this method in my spring service, but i get the same warning.

Edit with the Locator that work fine

Just strange i need to put bean in the applicationContext, context:annotation and context:component-scan seem useless

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The domain type org.calibra.domain.Account has no Account findAccount(java.lang.Long) method.

If you don't provide a find method of some kind, RequestFactory has no way of reconstituting objects when they get to the server - it can only create brand new ones, which prevents it from merging with existing data. Take this away, and you might as well have RPC again.

If you don't want static methods, provide a `Locator` instance which is able to find objects. From https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory#locators:

> What if you don't want to implement persistence code in an entity itself? To implement the required entity locator methods, create an entity locator class that extends Locator:

```
public class EmployeeLocator extends Locator<Employee, Long> {
  @Override
  public Employee create(Class<? extends Employee> clazz)
  {
    return new Employee();
  }
  ...
}
```

> Then associate it with the entity in the @ProxyFor annotation:

```
@ProxyFor(value = Employee.class, locator = EmployeeLocator.class)
public interface EmployeeProxy extends EntityProxy {
  ...
}
```

You'll need to implement all of the methods, not just create - and the main one you are interested in is `find(Class, Long)`. It may be possible to use one single `Locator` type for all proxies - as of 2.4.0 and 2.5.0-rc1 it is safe to fail to implement `getDomainType()`, and all of the other methods that need to know the exact type are provided with it as an argument.

Here is an example of what this can look like with JPA and Guice, but I think the idea is clear enough that it can be implemented with Spring and whatever persistence mechanism you are using. Here, all entities are expected to implement HasVersionAndId, allowing the locator to generalize on how to invoke getVersion and getId - you might have your own base class for all persisted entities.

(from https://github.com/niloc132/tvguide-sample-parent/blob/master/tvguide-client/src/main/java/com/acme/gwt/server/InjectingLocator.java)

```
public class InjectingLocator<T extends HasVersionAndId> extends Locator<T, Long> {
  @Inject
  Provider<EntityManager> data;

  @Inject
  Injector injector;

  @Override
  public T create(Class<? extends T> clazz) {
    return injector.getInstance(clazz);
  }

  @Override
  public T find(Class<? extends T> clazz, Long id) {
    return data.get().find(clazz, id);
  }

  @Override
  public Class<T> getDomainType() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();//unused
  }

  @Override
  public Long getId(T domainObject) {
    return domainObject.getId();
  }

  @Override
  public Class<Long> getIdType() {
    return Long.class;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getVersion(T domainObject) {
    return domainObject.getVersion();
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for all this info. After reading, there are a couple of thing i don't understand.  
I'm not sure to fully understand where to put my spring service, spring dao, method needed by locator.  
  
I guess  
  
I need to create a locator with specific method create and so on...  
I just use spring jdbc... so i don't have a entityManager  
I'm not sure but this class will need a spring dao (surely same dao than my spring service...) for the find method  
My spring service will have a spring dao  
My AccountRequest will continue to use the spring service  
My proxy will use my locator

Comment: An EntityManager is more or less a specific DAO, so just replace your dao in there - something that can find/create instances. Once you declare a `Locator` is just a matter of referencing it from your `@ProxyFor` annotation, and letting RF create it. You can influence this creation by subclassing RemoteServiceServlet and passing a custom `ServiceLayerDecorator` instance in the constructor. It is then up to you how to tie the Locator or the SLD into Spring to get references to the DAO bean.

Comment: thank, that work i posted the change.  Is it usefull to put findAccount in the service?  The only boring thing it's spring, i don't understand with i need to put the bean in the applicationContext. I thought than context:annotation-config and contex:component-scan avoid to put bean setup in xml file.